# Not able to change <label> text using jquery in IE

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to change label value using JQuery.

```
$("#labelId").text('Some Text here:');
```

although it is working in mozilla and chrome but it is not working in IE (any versions).

What should be the solution for this?

Comment: Can you put actual HTML against which you use this code please?

Comment: any version of IE specific?  in IE8 it works
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/WnJTc/ please verify you don't have any other javascript errors before this line of code

Comment: sounds like your id isnt unique

Comment: @Sander: I do not have any other javascript errors before this line of code. I tried it out in jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/WnJTc there also it did not change text on click of "Run" but in mozilla it does change.

Comment: @Andy I checked in my code, id is unique.

Comment: @AmiM the jsFiddle i posted above does work in IE8, it does not need to work on 'Run' it works when loading already, the preview says "bla" which is what jquery added in there... the default text was 'test'

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$("[id*='lblFullName']").text($("[name$='txtfirstname']")[0].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your jquery js file with this **http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js**

Actually I have faced similar sort of issue. When I tried using this URL & downloaded it then it worked perfectly to me.